# This is returning the error "Input string is not in correct format" can anyone see why?

Tags: c#, winforms, double

> double CoordinatesX = Convert.ToDouble(((((-1.2170 -
>   (Convert.ToDouble(labelLonR.Text))) * -1) * (638 / 0.0548))));

Input string in incorrect format? I can't see how, I have converted all of it to a double!

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What text is contained in `labelLonR.Text` ?

Comment: the problem is the text contained in labelLonR.Text. Probably is Empty. Verify that

Comment: The text is not empty, it contains a number for example 50.339

Comment: It could also include negative numbers like -1.9584, not sure whether that is relevant

Comment: What happens if you remove the outermost Convert.ToDouble?

Comment: Try putting `Convert.ToDouble(labelLonR.Text)` on a different line and storing it, then using that result here.  Which line does it error on?

Answer (score 4):

This is probably a problem with your culture setting.

Example: "123.12" isn't a valid double with my current culture settings but "123,12" would be.

Solution:

```
Convert.ToDouble("123.12", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Use [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) when you aren't sure what format the text will have.
To quote from msdn:

> The invariant culture is culture-insensitive; it is associated with the English language but not with any country/region. You specify the invariant culture by name by using an empty string ("") in the call to a CultureInfo instantiation method. CultureInfo.InvariantCulture also retrieves an instance of the invariant culture. It can be used in almost any method in the System.Globalization namespace that requires a culture. The objects returned by properties such as CompareInfo, DateTimeFormat, and NumberFormat also reflect the string comparison and formatting conventions of the invariant culture.
>
> Unlike culture-sensitive data, which is subject to change by user customization or by updates to the .NET Framework or the operating system, invariant culture data is stable over time and across installed cultures and cannot be customized by users. This makes the invariant culture particularly useful for operations that require culture-independent results, such as formatting and parsing operations that persist formatted data, or sorting and ordering operations that require that data be displayed in a fixed order regardless of culture.

On a different note, you can delete some parentheses that outer Convert.ToDouble and make the resulting assignment much nicer

```
double CoordinatesX = (1.2170 + Convert.ToDouble(labelLonR.Text)) * 638 / 0.0548
```

**Edit**: As others have pointed out, it's a good idea to do validation on your property, especially if it's an input from a user.

Comment: It seems that this gets rid of the error thankyou :)

Comment: @user1744093 You are welcome - I'd appreciate it if you marked my answer as answer.

Answer (score 0):

labelLonR.Text could be null and therefore cannot be converted to double.

Use the **Double.TryParse** method which will convert your string to a double and will return whether the conversion succeeded or failed. 
Once that is checked, proceed with your variable initialization.

Comment: Convert.ToDouble handles null

Comment: If `labelLonR.Text` is null, then `Convert.ToDouble` would succeed and return zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
double value = 0;
double.TryParse(labelLonR.Text, out value);
double CoordinatesX = Convert.ToDouble(((((-1.2170 - value ) * -1) * (638 / 0.0548))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. If it throws this Exception, you will know what the problem is...

```
double lonR;
double CoordinatesX;
if (double.TryParse(labelLonR.Text, out lonR))
    CoordinatesX = ((-1.2170 - lonR) * -1) * (638 / 0.0548);
else
    throw new Exception("The lonR format is Incorrect!");
```

I prefer to use TryParse instead of Convert.

Answer (score 0):

LINQPad

```
string value = "50.339";
double CoordinatesX = Convert.ToDouble(((((-1.2170 - (Convert.ToDouble(value))) * -1) * (638 / 0.0548))));

CoordinatesX.Dump();
```

returns 600232.262773723

I'm suggesting that you do not have "50.339" in the labelLonR.Text . null returns 14168.7226277372, so I'm going with a non-number value.  You should prefer using the Convert.ToDouble() with the overload IFormatProvider.  While your accountant may implicitly understand (50.339) is a negative number the CLS does not.